# What is a unitary post synaptic potential?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

I am reading the paper [Cooperative subnetworks of molecularly similar interneurons in mouse neocortex](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27021171) and have encountered the term:
"Unitary (excitatory or inhibitory) post synaptic potential".
I know what is an excitatory (or inhibitory) post synaptic potential.
But what does the unitary refers to?

Thanks!

Comment: Unitary EPSPs is the EPSP contributed by a single presynaptic fibre.

Comment: Does it mean a single synapse?

Comment: No, it means a single presynaptic fibre (which can make several synapses with a postsynaptic fibre).